# httpd.conf for case-insensitive file serving

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I'm a complete newbie with regard to managing Apache, so excuse me if I'm phrasing something incorrectly.

I have a web site -- say, `http://domain.com`. The problem is that when I try to open `http://domain.com/index.html` in a web browser it displays the page, but when I attempt to access `http://domain.com/Index.html` (note capital I), it responds with HTTP 404.

How do I configure Apache to serve both these files (and directories, for that matter) in a case-insensitive manner? Current `httpd.conf` is [here](http://pastie.org/541376).

**EDIT** [Dan C](https://serverfault.com/users/7083/dan-c), thanks for a hint. I basically want to allow users to download files from my server and don't really want them to be aware that `Index.html` and `index.html` are in fact different.

I'm also very willing to know as to what are the ramifications of this decision.

Comment: It would be good to add why you wish to do this and whether you wish to apply it to other files as well.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which is already loaded in your config.

Assuming your files are all in lower case (this may be a dangerous assumption):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${tolower:$1}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running apache on a linux server the problem is that it uses the underlying linux case sensitive file system, you could look at ReWrite as mentioned by matt.

Another option is the mod_speling module (yes it is one L) for apache, mentioned > [here](http://keystoneit.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/making-apache-case-insensitive/) < but I think that will only look for one spelling error and also might slow access down if there is a lot of files in one directory

Hope that helps

Comment: If using on Apache 2.2 this can even be limited to case only by using `CheckCaseOnly` directive.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really work with httpd.conf.
As said, the problem is that the Linux-filesystem you're on is case-sensitive.

I know of one method that works for sure:
Put your web-application into /opt/www/yourapplication

Then make an SMB share of /opt/www for localhost only

then mount the Samba share to /var/www

Samba is for Windows-shares, and windows shares are case-insensitive, so Samba will take care of the case-sensitiviy for you, making everything LOWERCASE internally.

Comment: Addendum: You can also create a VFAT file system and permanently mount it, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1497253 for more information. That way you don't need samba, which means this way it is far more secure and stable.